# Fast cbind and rbind in R

Tags: r, matrix

The cbind and rbind functions are exteremly slow when joining large matrices. What is the fastest way to implement the code below which is joining many matrices

```
library(Matrix)

cy11=function(a,b,H){
d=outer(a,b,`-`);I=outer(a,b,`==`)
H[1]^2*d^2/H[2]^2+I*H[3]^2
}

x0=c(1,1,0.05)
```

I have 100 vectors assume here they are from rnorm Ex :

```
z=list()
for (i in 1:100)
{
a=rnorm(50,0,10)
b=rnorm(50,0,10)
z[[i]]=cy11(a,a,x0)
}
do.call("rbind",z)
```

What is the best way to rbind or cbind these matrices
Also, What is the faster way to create a diagonal matrix from these matrices, I know I can do that through bdaig(z) (In the matrix package) but this is very slow.

Comment: Did you mean something like `do.call("rbind",z)` at the end? And is your real data much, much larger, because this particular example runs rather fast for me.

Comment: Yes I mean do.call("rbind",z) my data is much larger and any second faster speed will be exteremely helpfull for my application as long as it is done in R

Comment: @joran do you know also a fast way to make a block diagonal matrix othet that the bdiag function in the Matrix library

Comment: @jenesaisquoi (I) is an indicator function it just gives zero or 1. Should I provide my full code ?

Comment: I would investigate two things: (1) Initialize `z` to be a list of matrices of the appropriate dimension from the start, maybe using `replicate`, (2) try making them `data.table`s rather than matrices and use `data.table::rbindlist`.

Comment: @joran What about the bdiag function is I want to create from them a block diagonal matrix instead of binding them by row. It seems do.call("rbind",z) is exteremly fast is there something similair for bdiag ?

Comment: I didn't address the `bdiag` aspect of your question because I don't know the answer.